# I have the following error when creating a war of a spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, maven

the error I get is the following

```
org.eclipse.core.commands.ExecutionException: Error exportingC:/Users/Frederick/Downloads/war/Nueva carpeta/Prueba-Tecnica-Amaris.war
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl$1.run(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:385)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2380)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2405)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.runOperation(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:360)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.doExecute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:247)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.executeImpl(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:219)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.cacheThreadAndContinue(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.execute(DataModelPausibleOperationImpl.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.wst.common.frameworks.internal.datamodel.ui.DataModelWizard$1CatchThrowableRunnableWithProgress.run(DataModelWizard.java:220)
    at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:122)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot read the array length because "moduleParticipants" is null
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.getParticipants(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.JavaEEComponentExportOperation.createFlatComponentArchiver(JavaEEComponentExportOperation.java:91)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.export(ComponentExportOperation.java:191)
    at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.internal.archive.operations.ComponentExportOperation.execute(ComponentExportOperation.java:136)
    ... 11 more
```

this is my configuration file

`

4.0.0

org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-parent
3.1.0
 

api-rest
test
0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
war
tests
test

<java.version>20</java.version>



org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web


org.springframework.boot
spring-boot-starter-web-services

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

`

Comment: Try to build that on plain command line....

Comment: Try to always use maven package command from CLI to generate war/jar depending on the packaging type - mvn package spring-boot:repackage. It was not advisable to generate executables through Editors. Please refer to the https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/3.1.0/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.